# Open ionic app from browser in device

Tags: android, cordova, browser, cordova-plugins

Is there any way to open a check with Ionic + Cordova from the device's browser application. I tested some methods but my case is useless. Maybe there is not a global way as I need, but if you only need to know the name of the application package could be called. The idea is not to touch the application if not from a common html, open it. Will this be possible? Greetings and thanks for your help!

Comment: You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102528/android-how-to-create-custom-url-scheme-with-the-given-format-myapp-http, but idk if Ionic + Cordova supports that

Comment: thanks!! I'll keep an eye!