# Android create custom scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

How to create custom scheme for android so then I can use it in intent filter. My url is https://myquest.io/?ref=abc here abc will change with different user. I will replace "abc" with different user id and launch gmail app.Then when user clicks the link it will be captured by intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="Quest"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

I tried using `<a href="https://myquest.io">Quest</a>`, but it is not working.Can anybody help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102528/android-how-to-create-custom-url-scheme-with-the-given-format-myapp-http

Comment: yes I tried that too instead of https i give Quest and in scheme also I give Quest, but it always launch chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
           <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myquest.io"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: please can you select the answer for future references ?